# One radio button for yes no values in Angular

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, forms, angularjs

I have a list of questions in a form that need a response of yes or no. I want to use one radio button (checked is 'Yes', unchecked is 'No). I'm using Angular and Rails. I thought of using a directive for radios with a Yes/No answer, but I'm just not sure on the logic.

Comment: Why would you need js here?

Answer (score 1):

You're talking about a checkbox, not a radio button. It doesn't really make sense to use a radio button when there's only one choice.

Radio buttons are called "radio buttons" because there's always supposed to be exactly one button selected in a physical set of radio buttons. I know this to be true because I remember when car radios had *real* radio buttons, and I was reliably yelled at whenever I tried to make the row of buttons straight so that no button was pressed.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need JS. Just use checkboxes.

Radio buttons are used where there are multiple options for, say, a question.

Answer (score 0):

Just use something like this

```
<%= form_tag '/some_url' do %>
radio_button_tag 'answer', 'yes'  
radio_button_tag 'answer', 'no'  
<%= submit_tag %>
<% end %>
```